# R plotly subplot piecharts: object 'x' not found, despite being dataframe column name

Tags: r, dplyr, r-plotly

Trying to create subplots of piecharts following basic tutorial online.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
     seed aae bge pte tca
1  AUUGCA   2   4   3   1
2  CACUGG   2   0   0  10
3  UUGUUC   1   1   1   1
4  UUUGAU   1   1   1   0
5  ACUGGC   1   1   0   1
6  AAAUGC   1   1   2   0
7  AUCACA   8   5   9   0
```

I would like 4 piecharts (aae-tca columns), each showing the counts in their column of the respective seed seq (column 1). The code I've used is below, however I get the error "Error in eval(expr, data, expr_env) : object 'seed' not found".

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

p <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_pie(data = count(df, aae), labels = ~seed, values = ~aae,
          name = "A. aeg", domain = list(row = 0, column = 0)) %>%
  add_pie(data = count(df, bge), labels = ~seed, values = ~bge,
          name = "B .ger", domain = list(row = 0, column = 1)) %>%
  add_pie(data = count(df, pte), labels = ~seed, values = ~pte,
          name = "P. tep", domain = list(row = 1, column = 0)) %>%
  add_pie(data = count(df, tca), labels = ~seed, values = ~tcas,
          name = "T. cas", domain = list(row = 1, column = 1))%>%
  layout(title = "Pie Charts with Subplots", showlegend = F,
         grid=list(rows=2, columns=2),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

p
```

Comment: Have a look at `count(df, aae)` for example. It does not contain the column `seed` and thus it is not found in the data and throws an error. Replace `df` with `group_by(df, seed)` in each `count` - call and it works. However in your example no seed_seq is duplicated so you might as well only use `data = df`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need use `count()` in pie plots, the `add_pie()` do this for you.
Just remove the `data = count(df, ...)` of your code.

Like this:

```
# yours data
df = data.frame(
  seed =c("AUUGCA" ,"CACUGG" ,"UUGUUC" ,"UUUGAU" ,"ACUGGC" ,"AAAUGC" ,"AUCACA" ),
  aae=c(2 ,2 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,8 ),
  bge=c(4, 0, 1, 1, 1,  1,  5), 
  pte =c(3 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,2 ,9 ),
  tca = c(1,10,1,0,1,0,0)
)

library(plotly)

# Make pies

df%>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_pie(labels = ~seed, values = ~aae,
          name = "A. aeg", domain = list(row = 0, column = 0)) %>%
  add_pie(labels = ~seed, values = ~bge,
          name = "B .ger", domain = list(row = 0, column = 1)) %>%
  add_pie(labels = ~seed, values = ~pte,
          name = "P. tep", domain = list(row = 1, column = 0)) %>%
  add_pie(labels = ~seed, values = ~tca,
          name = "T. cas", domain = list(row = 1, column = 1))%>%
  layout(title = "Pie Charts with Subplots", showlegend = F,
         grid=list(rows=2, columns=2),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

Here the output:

[image: pies]